# NuGet: 'StructureMap' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections.Concurrent'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, structuremap

Running Visual Studio 2012 and latest version of NuGet, version  3.5.0.1996.

When I try to add StructureMap as a dependency to my class project, I get this error:

```
PM> install-package structuremap
install-package : 'StructureMap' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections.Concurrent'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package structuremap
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have ran `nuget update -self`, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Overcome by adding this line to packages.config in the project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  ...
  <package id="StructureMap" version="4.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

And running this:

```
nuget update .\packages.config
```

I'm still in the dark as to why this is happening or which NuGet Visual Studio is actually using.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 uses NuGet 2.8. You can probably see it by looking at the extensions or the Visual Studio about page. You cannot update version of NuGet that is used by Visual Studio 2012. The error is because NuGet is too old and does not handle the target framework groups specified in the NuGet package.